# hide element in parent window when clicking image inside an iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I need to hide some buttons in a parent window while opening modal by clicking image inside an iframe.

Following is my code -

in parent window -

```
<iframe id="gallery" src="links/gallery.html" width="100%" frameborder="0" style="min-height: 100vh;
  max-height: 999px;></iframe>

<div id="max" class="abtbtn">
  <button><span class="fas fa-chevron-up"></span></button>
  <button><span class="fas fa-chevron-down"></span></button>
</div>
```

javascript:

```
var iframe = document.getElementById('gallery').contentWindow.find('img');
iframe.click.document.getElementById("max").style.display = "none";
```

in iframe -

```
<img id="portfolio" src="images/portfolios/web/4.jpg" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".portfolio1" alt="" />
```

I have tried so many ways but nothing works. Please help.. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

First, add this function to the parent window `JavaScript`:

```
function bindClick() {
  var iframe = document.getElementById("gallery");
  var innerDoc = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;
  innerDoc.getElementById("portfolio").addEventListener("click", function () {
    window.parent.document.getElementById("max").style.display = "none";
  });
}
```

Add a load handler to your `iframe`:

```
<iframe onload="bindClick()" id="gallery" src="links/gallery.html" ... >
```

Clicking on the `iframe` image hides the buttons in the parent:

[image]

Comment: it worked perfectly in firefox and edge. but not working in chrome..please help

Comment: @NamilZen For Chrome, you'll need to test things on a live server (`localhost` is fine, too). If you try to run things on, say, the OS filesystem, you'll get this error in Chrome: `Blocked a frame with origin "null" from accessing a cross-origin frame.`

Comment: @NamilZen If you're curious to learn more about same-origin policy restrictions please refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25098021/securityerror-blocked-a-frame-with-origin-from-accessing-a-cross-origin-frame?rq=1).